# .NET6: always get Null value when retrieving parameter from AWS paramter store by Configureation.GetSection(paramKey).Get<ParameterObject>()

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

For instance, I put the following JSON string as the string value of key `/SampleApi/BasicAuthOptions`

```
{
  "AccessKey": "develop",
  "AccessSecret": "9a55w0rd123"
}
```

by `Console.WriteLine(webApplicationBuilder.Configuration.GetSection("/SampleApi:BasicAuthOptions").Value)` I can get exactly the same value as above. The problem is that `webApplicationBuilder.Configuration.GetSection("/SampleApi:BasicAuthOptions").Get<BasicAuthOptions>()` always returns null while `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<BasicAuthOptions>(webApplicationBuilder.Configuration.GetSection("/SampleApi:BasicAuthOptions").Value)` get can the correct object.

I never meet this issue when I retrieve parameters from Appsettings.json.
I am new to the AWS parameter store; maybe I shouldn't save a JSON string as a pure string parameter in the AWS parameter store? If so what is the correct way to keep a JSON value in the parameter store? I assume it is a typical scenario; why doesn't it work as I expect?